# customize user session data in keycloak

Tags: session, attributes, keycloak, keycloak-rest-api

I used this curl command to retrieve session details for a user in keycloak:

```
curl -X GET \
-H 'Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN' \
http://192.168.X.X:8080/auth/admin/realms/$REALM_NAME/users/$ID_OF_CLIENT/sessions
```

and in response we have:

```
[{
  "id":"194d6b10-5b94-42c3-86d8-4d1780f70f52",
  "username":"admin",
  "userId":"e258f775-3597-4a72-a490-7bgd7c1cdfdb",
  "ipAddress":"192.168.X.X",
  "start":1589006511000,
  "lastAccess":1589007060000,
  "clients" :
       {
         "53d98bf8-fffd-484c-aae8-500a7cf7a8b6":"authz-servlet",
         "9bc56128-972e-41fe-8946-3ce4b5660e24":"authz-client-app3"
       }
 }]
```

now I need to add some more details in the session information such as browser version for the logged-in user. Is there any way to add these details?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to take a look at `userinfo` OIDC endpoint. Comparing to you current approach (utilizing Admin REST Api with administrative token) it accepts token issued for end user. If it ok for you, you will be able to customize endpoint output as you want. Customization available at **Client Scopes** and **Mappers** tabs in client settings.

Set of mappers available by default is quite wide but
i'm afraid by default Keycloak is not preserve information about UA, so you have to develop your own logic to extract it during login flow and than to store it in user session. If you are not familiar with implementing Keycloak Java SPI you can try to do implement your logic via JS mapper.

https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/index.html#_protocol-mappers_oidc-user-session-note-mappers
https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/#_script_providers

AFAIK some examples should be in keycloak github

Comment: as you said, I need to implement it by myself, do you have any example? another question, In Mappers and Client Scope this is possible to make new details available in access token and id token, I need this information to be available in user session.

Comment: @Maryam i'm don't know about your use case but in general answer is "Yes". Access token fields could be populated by data from user properties, user attributes or even user session. But to find which data available in user session you have to dig into Keycloak server sources. Find usages of `UserSessionModel.note.put()`. If there is not data you interested for you'll have to implement corresponding mapper by yourself. Keycloak sources is you friend. Here is example of how to do it with Java https://github.com/mschwartau/keycloak-custom-protocol-mapper-example